# An error occurred while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done while there is no AsyncTask in the code

Tags: android, android-studio

I got this error in my code say there is an error in doInBackground method while I don't use AsyncTask in my code, instead, I am using Loader to load the data from SQLite database, How I could get an error in a method I didn't use or call in my code at any place.

the error occurs when I am trying to press the floatingactionbutton to open another activity, I have two modes for this activity depend on the user going to update or add a pet.

```
package com.example.android.pets;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


import com.example.android.pets.data.PetContract.PetEntry;

/**
 * Displays list of pets that were entered and stored in the app.
 */
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    //loader unique ID
    public static final int PET_LOADER = 0;
    // If non-null, this is the current filter the user has provided.
   private String mCurFilter;
   // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data.
         private PetCursorAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

        // Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               startActivity(new Intent(CatalogActivity.this,EditorActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // Find the ListView which will be populated with the pet data
        ListView petListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Find and set empty view on the ListView, so that it only shows when the list has 0 items.
        View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        petListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

        mAdapter = new PetCursorAdapter(this,null);
        petListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(PET_LOADER,null,this);

        petListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this,EditorActivity.class);
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI,id);
                intent.setData(contentUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Helper method to insert hardcoded pet data into the database. For debugging purposes only.
     */
    private void insertPet() {
        // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
        // and Toto's pet attributes are the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "Toto");
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, "Promenader");
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, PetEntry.GENDER_MALE);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, 7);

        // Insert a new row for Toto into the provider using the ContentResolver.
        // Use the {@link PetEntry#CONTENT_URI} to indicate that we want to insert
        // into the pets database table.
        // Receive the new content URI that will allow us to access Toto's data in the future.
        Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_catalog.xml file.
        // This adds menu items to the app bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_catalog, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to a click on the "Insert dummy data" menu option
            case R.id.action_insert_dummy_data:
                insertPet();
                return true;
            // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
            case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
                // Do nothing for now
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                    Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = PetEntry.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        String [] projection = {PetEntry._ID,PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME,PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED};

        return new CursorLoader(getApplication(), baseUri,
                projection, null, null,
                null );
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}.
```

> Blockquote

```
public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

/** Create an instance from @link{PetDbHelper}*/
PetDbHelper mDbHelper;
/** EditText field to enter the pet's name */
private EditText mNameEditText;

/** Content URI for the existing pet (null if it's a new pet) */
private Uri mCurrentPetUri;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's breed */
private EditText mBreedEditText;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's weight */
private EditText mWeightEditText;

/** EditText field to enter the pet's gender */
private Spinner mGenderSpinner;

//the unique id of the loader
private final static int EXISTING_PET_LOADER = 0;
/**
 * Gender of the pet. The possible values are:
 * 0 for unknown gender, 1 for male, 2 for female.
 */
private int mGender = 0;
// get the title of the activity inside a variable
private CharSequence activityTitle = getTitle();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mCurrentPetUri = intent.getData();

    if (mCurrentPetUri == null){
        setTitle(R.string.editor_activity_title_new_pet);
    }else {
        setTitle(R.string.editor_activity_edit_pet);
    }

    // Find all relevant views that we will need to read user input from
    mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_name);
    mBreedEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_breed);
    mWeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_weight);
    mGenderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);

    // To access our database, we instantiate our subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
    // and pass the context, which is the current activity.
    mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_PET_LOADER, null, this);

    setupSpinner();
}

/**
 * Setup the dropdown spinner that allows the user to select the gender of the pet.
 */
private void setupSpinner() {
    // Create adapter for spinner. The list options are from the String array it will use
    // the spinner will use the default layout
    ArrayAdapter genderSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.array_gender_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify dropdown layout style - simple list view with 1 item per line
    genderSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    mGenderSpinner.setAdapter(genderSpinnerAdapter);

    // Set the integer mSelected to the constant values
    mGenderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_male))) {
                    mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_MALE; // Male
                } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_female))) {
                    mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALE; // Female
                } else {
                    mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN; // Unknown
                }
            }
        }

        // Because AdapterView is an abstract class, onNothingSelected must be defined
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mGender = 0; // Unknown
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get user input from editor and save new pet into database.
 */
private void savePet() {


        // Read from input fields
        // Use trim to eliminate leading or trailing white space
        String nameString = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String breedString = mBreedEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String weightString = mWeightEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    // If the weight is not provided by the user, don't try to parse the string into an
    // integer value. Use 0 by default.
    int weight = 0;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(weightString)) {
        weight = Integer.parseInt(weightString);
    }


        if (mCurrentPetUri == null &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(nameString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(breedString) &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(weightString) && mGender == PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN) {return;}


        // Create a ContentValues object where column names are the keys,
        // and pet attributes from the editor are the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, nameString);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, breedString);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, mGender);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, weight);


        // Determine if this is a new or existing pet by checking if mCurrentPetUri is null or not
        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {
            // This is a NEW pet, so insert a new pet into the provider,
            // returning the content URI for the new pet.
            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
            // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the insertion was successful.
            if (newUri == null) {
                // If the new content URI is null, then there was an error with insertion.
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_failed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast.
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_successful),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }else {
            // Otherwise this is an EXISTING pet, so update the pet with content URI: mCurrentPetUri
            // and pass in the new ContentValues. Pass in null for the selection and selection args
            // because mCurrentPetUri will already identify the correct row in the database that
            // we want to modify.
            int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentPetUri, values, null, null);
            // Show a toast message depending on whether or not the update was successful.
            if (rowsAffected == 0) {
                // If no rows were affected, then there was an error with the update.
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_update_pet_failed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, the update was successful and we can display a toast.
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_update_pet_successful),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu options from the res/menu/menu_editor.xml file.
    // This adds menu items to the app bar.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_editor, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to a click on the "Save" menu option
        case R.id.action_save:
            //save pet for data base

            savePet();
            finish();

            return true;
        // Respond to a click on the "Delete" menu option
        case R.id.action_delete:
            // Do nothing for now
            return true;
        // Respond to a click on the "Up" arrow button in the app bar
        case android.R.id.home:
            // Navigate back to parent activity (CatalogActivity)
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public Loader <Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Since the editor shows all pet attributes, define a projection that contains
    // all columns from the pet table
    String[] projection = {
            PetEntry._ID,
            PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME,
            PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED,
            PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER,
            PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT };

    // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
    return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
            mCurrentPetUri,         // Query the content URI for the current pet
            projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
            null,                   // No selection clause
            null,                   // No selection arguments
            null);                  // Default sort order
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // Find the columns of pet attributes that we're interested in
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME);
        int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED);
        int genderColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER);
        int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);

        // Extract out the value from the Cursor for the given column index
        String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        String breed = cursor.getString(breedColumnIndex);
        int gender = cursor.getInt(genderColumnIndex);
        int weight = cursor.getInt(weightColumnIndex);

        // Update the views on the screen with the values from the database
        mNameEditText.setText(name);
        mBreedEditText.setText(breed);
        mWeightEditText.setText(Integer.toString(weight));

        // Gender is a dropdown spinner, so map the constant value from the database
        // into one of the dropdown options (0 is Unknown, 1 is Male, 2 is Female).
        // Then call setSelection() so that option is displayed on screen as the current selection.
        switch (gender) {
            case PetEntry.GENDER_MALE:
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(1);
                break;
            case PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALE:
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(2);
                break;
            default:
                mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // If the loader is invalidated, clear out all the data from the input fields.
    mNameEditText.setText("");
    mBreedEditText.setText("");
    mWeightEditText.setText("");
    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0); // Select "Unknown" gender
}
```

}.

```
08-04 04:28:57.457 11642-11900/com.example.android.pets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #7
Process: com.example.android.pets, PID: 11642
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:128)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:737)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:704)
    at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
    at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:54)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:315)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
    at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:64)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using asynctask directly, but the AsyncTaskLoader class is using it. You have to learn reading the logs. There says 'Dude, you aren't sending anything in the URI, and therefore the background process is failing'.